# Can't route to another page in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble routing to another page. When clicking the route it changes the link but stays on the same. Sorry in advance I'm a beginner. Here is a picture of the website and my code for the route page.

```
import React from "react";

    const Blank2 = () => {
      return <main id="mainContent">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row justify-content-center mt-5 p-0">
            <h3>Blank2</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    }
    export default Blank2;
```

my app.js

```
    import React from "react";
    import { Routes ,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    import "./App.css";
    import NavBar from "./components/NavBar/NavBar";
    import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer";
    
    import VolcanoInfo from "./components/VolcanoInfo/VolcanoInfo";
    
    import Blank1 from "./components/Blank1/Blank1";
    
    import Blank2 from "./components/Blank2/Blank2";
    
    import Blank3 from "./components/Blank3/Blank3";
    
    import image from './image.jpg';
    
    //TODO Web Template Studio: Add routes for your new pages here.
    const App = () => {
        return (
          
          <React.Fragment>
            <NavBar />
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path = "/VolcanoInfo" component = { VolcanoInfo } />
              <Route path = "/Blank1" component = { Blank1 } />
              <Route path = "/Blank2" component = { Blank2 } />
              <Route path = "/Blank3" component = { Blank3 } />
            </Routes>
            <Footer />
          </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
    
    <header className="App-header">
      <img src={image} className="image" alt="image" />
    </header>
    
    
    export default App;
```

[website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16fqt.png)

Comment: I don't see router in your code.

Comment: can u put all your code?

Comment: @VMT i updated it with my app.js

Comment: What version of react-router are you using? The API changed significantly from v5 to v6.

Comment: @Andy do you know the command line to see what version?

Comment: @JaydenRee look in your `package.json`. It will be referenced there under `dependencies`.

Comment: @andy v6 is the version im on

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-to-react-router-v6

Comment: Not related to the question but I noticed the App component has a `<header>` outside the render function, Move it inside the `React.Fragment` tags or you will never see it

Comment: You did `import Blank1 from "./components/Blank1/Blank1";` or `import Blank2 from "./components/Blank2/Blank2";`. The file's names come twice. isn't it wrong?

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi nah cause the blank1 is a folder and then there is a blank1 file inside that folder

Answer (score 2):

For React Router v6, there are couple of things being done wrong here. You need to replace `component` with `element` and make use of `BrowserRouter` or `HashRouter`. Also we don't need `exact` from react-router v6. Your code would look something like this

```
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

...

<BrowserRouter>
   <NavBar />
   <Routes>
      <Route path = "/VolcanoInfo" element= { <VolcanoInfo /> } />
      <Route path = "/Blank1" element = { <Blank1 /> } />
      <Route path = "/Blank2" element = { <Blank2 /> } />
      <Route path = "/Blank3" element = { <Blank3 /> } />
   </Routes>
   <Footer />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're using `react-router-dom` **v6**.
React Router Dom is actually easy to use but sometimes we can get mixed up with the older version.

[Here's the link to the official v6 document on configuring routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview).

- You need to have a `<BrowserRouter>` wrap over your routes.
- Instead of `component` attribute, v6 uses `element` and then pass in the component you want to route. (Ex: `element={<Blank1 />}`)

More details in the documentation above. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial for React Router v6 [in here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial). And many change from v5 to v6 according to [this doc](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrading-from-v5) :

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes ,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./App.css";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar/NavBar";
import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer";

import VolcanoInfo from "./components/VolcanoInfo/VolcanoInfo";

import Blank1 from "./components/Blank1/Blank1";

import Blank2 from "./components/Blank2/Blank2";

import Blank3 from "./components/Blank3/Blank3";

import image from './image.jpg';

//TODO Web Template Studio: Add routes for your new pages here.
const App = () => {
    return (
      
      <BrowserRouter>
        <header className="App-header">
           <img src={image} className="image" alt="image" />
        </header>
        <NavBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path = "/VolcanoInfo" element= { <VolcanoInfo /> } />
          <Route path = "/Blank1" element= { <Blank1 />} />
          <Route path = "/Blank2" element= { <Blank2 />} />
          <Route path = "/Blank3" element= { <Blank3 />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
}




export default App;
```